# Rank top N in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel that presents names and sales data, I would like to add additional column (rank) that will place a number of rank (5,10,25,Others) that means that if name A is in the top 5 it all have 5 in its rank column.

The goal of this calculation is to create a slicer that shows (5,10,25,Others) which will allow me to filter sales and names by rank.

1. Is it possible to do it and how?
2. Is there some other approach that will be more efficient?

[image: Excel Table]

Comment: For the first part I answered your question, but I realized that you are looking for something more. Can you please explain what else do you need?

Comment: Your answer is great, I just combined it with an If statement and that is all

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, It's possible and actually easy.

Type into **C1** cell, (or *The first cell of Rank column*)

`=RANK.EQ($B1,$B:$B,0)`

And drag this formula till the end.

This one will sort the list in descending order.
 If you wish to get the rank numbers in ascending number change the 0 as 1.